# Using a struct and dynamically allocated memory to write all the lines from a text file in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have written a program in C to represent a quiz game. Each question is an individual line of a text file. I am using a struct to represent the array of questions. It begins by taking some user input, then counts the amount of text lines in the file. It then allocated the amount of memory needed for the structs before reading each line of the file into the struct. When I print out the elements in the struct it prints out 20 lines of errors instead of the file values. What am I doing incorrectly? I have included a screenshot of some of lines of the file also.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#define filepath "Questions_Answers"
#define CAPACITY 120

typedef struct
{
char* questions;
} Lines;

int setupGame(int *difficulty);

int main() {

int difficulty;                                     //Set difficulty out of ten of the quiz
int numberOfLines = 0;                              //Set the number of lines counted in the file initially to zero
int question_length;
char answer[20];
char c;

//Calls setup game function which sets the difficulty
difficulty = setupGame(&difficulty);

FILE* fPointer = fopen(filepath, "r");              //Points to the address of a File not yet known

//If the file has no content, print error and end program
if (fPointer == NULL) {
    perror("Error opening file");
    return -1;
}

// Extract characters from file and store in character c 
for (c = getc(fPointer); c != EOF; c = getc(fPointer)) {
    if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline 
        numberOfLines++;
}

numberOfLines = numberOfLines + 1;

printf("Number of questions in quiz - %d\n", numberOfLines);

Lines *lines = malloc(sizeof(Lines) * numberOfLines); // allocate memory for questions

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {

    int lengthOfQuestion = 150;

    lines[i].questions = malloc(sizeof(char) * (lengthOfQuestion + 1));
    fscanf(fPointer, "%s", lines[i].questions);
    printf("%s\n", lines[i].questions);
}

fclose(fPointer);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    free(lines[i].questions);
    }

free(lines);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `fclose(fPointer);` then reopen before you want to get questions from the file.

```
fclose(fPointer);
fPointer = fopen("input.txt", "r");
```

`fscanf` reads word by word not whole the line. You should use `fgets()` or `getline()`.

I see in your code, you init the length of all questions by `150`

```
int lengthOfQuestion = 150;
```

So, i think, it's easier when you declare the struct (you can use pointer if you want):

```
typedef struct
{
    char questions[150];
} Lines;
```

You should use one loop for storing and increasing the number of lines. The code will be more readable. For example:

```
char line[150];
lines = malloc(sizeof(Lines));
if(!lines) {// handle the error}
while (fgets(fPointer, sizeof(line), line)) {
    strcpy(lines[numberOfLines].question, line);
    numberOfLines++;
    lines = realloc(lines, sizeof(Lines) * numberOfLines);
    if(!line) {// handle the error}

}
```

Comment: I see now that I wasn't able to access the values due to the stream not being closed. Which wouldn't have been an issue if I counted the lines and read in the same loop as you showed above. Thanks!